# Avenger 220 - pickup become Unusual After 10000 km

Tags: motorcycle, oil-change, torque, bajaj, avenger-mc

I often ride long ride on Avenger Cruise(150-300 Km)

I have done all the Service as per manual and Also done extra service from Authorized center.

but After last Service i m feeling that Avenger Doesn't Apply same Torque power as before. What cause made this happen?

Only 1 Mistake i have made. --> last Oil changed after 3500 km

Edit:
My Apology i forgot to mention that - yes it's making Sound like some plastic wrapper in between of Wheel

Last Service Include only basic Service- oil change +general Service(oiling parts + wash)

And not Sure about if it is related to Whether or not, but i m having this issue in Summer So , i guess may be because of hot Whether

Comment: Welcome to the site jeegnesh! We're going to need some more info to help you out. Does the vehicle sound any different? Does it lose power in a certain rev range or when it's hot/cold? What was involved in the last service (air/fuel/oil filter, fluids, etc?). I'm afraid this question will be removed unless you can add some details.

Comment: Which wheels are making the squealing noise?

Comment: it's coming From rear-wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your rear brakes checked for correct clearance, seems like they might be slightly locking while riding the bike. It would not just affect the torque, moreover it would kill the fuel efficiency. How long has it been since you changed your air filter?

Comment: not yet, Coz i purchased bike  Aug 2016 and No one recommend it.

Comment: You please change it. I assure you the difference will be felt. Get it changed today.

Comment: Perfect. Now you've restored the proper torque back to the rear wheel.